# Can cube of force be used as a reaction?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Example: A mage is casting a fireball at your party from the side. You see this, are you able to activate the cube as a reaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Cube of Force* states:

> **You can use an action** to press one of the cube's faces...

Nothing in the spell's description says anything about being able to use a reaction to activate the cube. As such, without some DM homebrewing, you can't use a reaction to activate it.

Answer (score 24):

**By RAW, yes, however it also costs you your action.**

PHB. pg 193: Under Actions in Combat; Ready (emphasis mine)

> Sometimes you want to get the jump on a foe or wait for
>   a particular circumstance before you act. To do so, you
>   can take the ***Ready*** action on your turn so that you can
>   act later in the round ***using your reaction.***
>   First, you decide what perceivable circumstance
>   will trigger your reaction. Then, ***you choose the action
>   you will take*** in response to that trigger, or you choose
>   to move up to your speed in response to it. Examples
>   include “If the cultist steps on the trapdoor, I’ll pull the
>   lever that opens it,” and “If the goblin steps next to me,
>   I move away.”
>   When the trigger occurs, you can either take your
>   reaction right after the trigger finishes or ignore
>   the trigger. Remember that you can take only one
>   reaction per round.
>
> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but
>   hold its energy, which you release with your reaction
>   when the trigger occurs. To be readied, a spell must
>   have a casting time o f 1 action, and holding onto the
>   spell’s magic requires concentration (explained in
>   chapter 10). If your concentration is broken, the spell
>   dissipates without taking effect. For example, if you are
>   concentrating on the web spell and ready magic missile,
>   your web spell ends, and if you take damage before
>   you release magic missile with your reaction, your
>   concentration might be broken.

So doing this burns your action for your turn in order to use your reaction to perform an action later. So in your case, if you wanted to react to the mage, then on your turn you would take your action to declare a ready action and say, "If that [insert mage here] casts a spell with an element I can recognize, then I will turn the proper side of the cube towards the spell in order to counter it."

This is a planned reaction which relies on anticipation, not a regular reaction.

Comment: Could be made more clear that you specifically have to plan this move out in advance.

Comment: The example ready trigger sentence doesn't make sense and could probably be improved by reviewing how the Cube is used.

Comment: The example is inclusive, but the specific wording of "choose the action you will take" leaves no room for misinterpretation at all.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli I mean the readied action is wrong, in the sense that it's valid to say, but does nothing useful. (Turning a side of the Cube toward the spell won't counter it, because that's not how the Cube is activated or works in general.)

Comment: I don't think you understand readied action. You can cast spells so long as they only cost 1 action using a ready action. The same goes for making an attack, ability check or anything else covered by an action. Just turning a cube is a free action that you could say your character is doing. The actual action of pressing the proper face is covered under the ready action. Again though, this relies heavily on anticipation, and your own character's ability to recognize the element being used.

Answer (score 2):

## By RAW, not spontaneously

The Cube of Force text states, in part (DMG p. 159):

> You can use an action to press one of the cube's faces...

The only things that are allowed during a *reaction* are things that are *stated* to occur as a reaction -- the most common example is an opportunity attack, but certain spells (*shield* and *counterspell* most notably) are also allowed as a reaction, which is as per the "1 reaction" casting time in their spell blocks.  Or as the PHB section on p.190 regarding reactions puts it:

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a special action called a reaction.

Comment: I'll be giving another edit in a couple of days to deal with readied actions more fully

Answer (score -1):

No.
But you could have your familiar use it, if it has hands, by holding its action. If it does not have hands, make a skeleton and have your familiar order the skeleton to hold its action to press a button. Make sure your buttons are clearly labeled in a language the undead can understand. Thus, in effect, you have it as a reaction, just not yours. Also, as it is an attuned item, you now have to maintain a designated cube zombie.